# Add daily data for every ID using forward fill for missing dates

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a  pandas dataframe that looks as below:

```
    id   date    value  name
0   C1  2017-01-01  31  Company 1
1   C1  2017-01-02  35  Company 1
2   C1  2017-01-03  32  Company 1
3   C1  2017-01-06  36  Company 1
4   C1  2017-01-07  35  Company 1
5   C1  2017-01-08  34  Company 1
6   C1  2017-01-10  33  Company 1
7   C2  2017-01-01  225 Company 2
8   C2  2017-01-02  223 Company 2
9   C2  2017-01-03  223 Company 2
10  C2  2017-01-06  220 Company 2
11  C2  2017-01-07  222 Company 2
12  C2  2017-01-08  225 Company 2
13  C2  2017-01-10  224 Company 2
14  C3  2017-01-08  340 Company 3
```

For this dataframe, the range for the date is **start_date 2017-01-01** and **end_date 2017-01-10** including both. That is all the data is in between those 2 dates.

I want to add new rows for the missing dates. For instance for id **C1**, there are missing values in the **value** column for **2017-01-04,2017-01-05,2017-01-09** and new rows should be added as below with **0** in the **value** column.

```
 C1 2017-01-04 0 Company1
 C1 2017-01-05 0 Company1
 C1 2017-01-09 0 Company1
```

Similarly for **C2**, there are missing values in the **value** column for **2017-01-04,2017-01-05,2017-01-09** and for **C3** there are missing values for **2017-01-01 to 2017-01-07 and 2017-01-09,2017-01-10**

I am struggling to figure out, how to perform such an operation of adding those rows using pandas. So, just looking for some help.

Comment: Is the *name* column always the same for each id? For instance, for C1 *company 1*, for C2 *company 2*?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: Made an answer as below. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to create all the dates you'd like to complete using `pandas.date_range` and then you can do an outer join between the complete dates with each sub data frame keyed on the *date* column, finally fill missing values with 0:

```
# create complete dates
dates = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range("2017-01-01", "2017-01-10")})

# convert date column to date time if it's not already
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

# merge complete dates with each sub data frame separately using groupby.apply
(df.groupby(['id', 'name'])['date', 'value']
 .apply(lambda g: g.merge(dates, how="outer"))
 .fillna(0)
 .reset_index(level=[0,1])
 .reset_index(drop=True))

#   id       name        date   value
#0  C1  Company 1   2017-01-01  31.0
#1  C1  Company 1   2017-01-02  35.0
#2  C1  Company 1   2017-01-03  32.0
#3  C1  Company 1   2017-01-06  36.0
#4  C1  Company 1   2017-01-07  35.0
#5  C1  Company 1   2017-01-08  34.0
#6  C1  Company 1   2017-01-10  33.0
#7  C1  Company 1   2017-01-04  0.0
#8  C1  Company 1   2017-01-05  0.0
#9  C1  Company 1   2017-01-09  0.0
# ...
```